# Querying XML with Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Consider the following XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <element>This is the first sentence.<button>Click</button>some more text.
</element>
</data>
```

I am using Python module xml.etree.ElementTree.
I know that I can access to elements and texts with the following Python code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

name = 'data.xml'
tree = ET.parse(name)
root = tree.getroot()
element = root[0].tag
first_text = root[0].text #This is the first sentence
button = root[0][0].tag #button
buttontext = root[0][0].text #click
```

But how do I access to text "some more text" with Python?
I haven't found the solution yet...
You can also suggest some other Python module if it's better way to do that.

That XML-code is just an example.

Comment: Use lxml library, it is way faster than the ET. Also, you could use xpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are looking for the `.tail` attribute of the `<button>` element: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail

Comment: great, please mark the answer as accepted. also consider lxml in case you need performance.